# Align the second line of an item same as the first line

Tags: latex3

I want to align the second & futher lines of my item same as the first one.

So far the code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12 pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  a4paper,
  total={170 mm,257 mm},
  left=20 mm,
  top=20 mm,
  }
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\setlength{\parindent}{2em}

\begin{document}
The conversion of Decimal number to n-Base can be performed bu using following steps:
    \begin{itemize}
        \setlength{\itemindent}{1cm}
        \item Separate the integer part and the fractional part from the given Decimal number.
        \item Repeatedly divide the integer part of the given Decimal number by N till the quotient becomes zero. 
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

which is producing the output as follows:

[image: Obtained output]

I want the output as follows:

[image]

Can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal self contained example instead of a sniplet. We don;t know if there are any packages messing with `itemize` in your document. The image you show is the default look for itemsize, so if you get something else, you need to show us a complete code that recreates that

Comment: I have edited the code

Comment: Thanks, and what is that `\itemindent` suppose to do? As mentioned in the answer below, use `enumitem` for configuring lists, doing it by hand like this is error prone

Comment: Thanks...for the help it is working

Comment: The problem is that the left margin is set BEFORE the \first \item, so attempting to set \leftmargin or \labelwidth inside itemize has no visible effect.

Comment: You can, however, set `\leftmargini` before itemize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `enumitem`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
 The conversion of Decimal number to n-Base can be performed bu using following steps:
\begin{itemize}[left=2\parindent]
  \item Separate the integer part and the fractional part from the given Decimal number.
  \item Repeatedly divide the integer part of the given Decimal number by N till the quotient becomes zero. 
\end{itemize} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help...It is working